# Is there a precedent of the IMF augmenting a loan due to considerations made as a result of a war?

Tags: egypt, international-monetary-fund

> Managing Director Kristalina Georgieva told Reuters on Friday that the
> IMF **was “seriously considering” a possible augmentation of Egypt’s
> $3bn loan programme due to economic difficulties posed by the
> Israel-Gaza war.**

https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/11/18/imf-could-augment-egypts-loan-programme-over-effects-of-gaza-war

> According to the IMF itself, it works to foster global growth and
> economic stability by providing policy advice and financing the
> members by working with developing countries to help them achieve
> macroeconomic stability and reduce poverty.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Monetary_Fund

Is there a precedent of the IMF augmenting a loan due to considerations made as a result of a war? It seems to be a weird thing for the IMF to do since the IMF is considered to be a lender of last resort who lend to prevent a speculative financial attacks and ensure macroeconomic stability and to a lesser degree reduce poverty, but here the IMF seems to be acting more like an aid agency. Is there a precedent for something like this happening in the past?

Comment: Ehh, probably Pakistan got a similar treatment during the War on Terror, at least in the early years. Whether the IMF was explicit about that, is another matter. A lot of the US aid was bilateral though see e.g. page 5 (45) in https://uwaterloo.ca/scholar/sites/ca.scholar/files/bmomani/files/the_imf_us_war_on_terrorism_and_pakistan_a_lesson_in_economic_statecraft.pdf

Comment: Ironically, perhaps, reading the whole piece, the US publicly took credit then for something they didn't actually do in the IMF meetings.